# ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for .. read timed out ERROR

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, tomcat, https

When I  call the  rest end point (Rest Template http client) "myservice..com/rest/api/" i get the below error sometime .What can be the cause of this error? And is this client or server error?

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "myservice..com/rest/api/": read timed out;
  exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: read timed out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the exception is **declarative** in nature. That exception signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept, as per Java API describes. In shorter words, there is a network connectivity issue that has nothing to do with your code.

A couple of questions that you may want to figure out first:

- Is the service `myservice..com/rest/api/` up? Is it visible from you computer/host?
- Can you hit it an `status` endpoint to check if it is alive?
- Can you make a different HTTP request to the API `GET`, `DELETE`?
- What happens if you query the endpoint with cURL or Postman?

Comment: And can you provide the Java API doc link

Comment: There you go, https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html

Comment: So u mean this issue is bcz of network issue?

Comment: Your question is very broad, _in general_, you get those exceptions when there is a **connectivity issue**. Although, I do encourage you to troubleshot it further. If your application is up and running and you can query other endpoints but not that one, there must be something of with your request, check the definition of the endpoint itself and double check your request.